# Man command surprisingly accepts arguments ``git diff``

Tags: ubuntu

Today, I accidentally typed `man git diff` which should give no results, as it should, according to the manual, be interpreted as page *diff* in section *git*. However, page *git-diff(1)* is actually shown.  How can that be? (Using man 2.5.7 as included in Ubuntu Lucid)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

man(1) on Ubuntu says:

```
--no-subpages
              By default, man will try to interpret pairs of manual page names given on the command line as
              equivalent to a single manual page name containing a hyphen.  This supports the  common  pat-
              tern  of  programs  that  implement  a number of subcommands, allowing them to provide manual
              pages for each that can be accessed using similar syntax as would be used to invoke the  sub-
              commands themselves.  For example:

                $ man -aw git diff
                /usr/share/man/man1/git-diff.1.gz

              To disable this behaviour, use the --no-subpages option.

                $ man -aw --no-subpages git diff
                /usr/share/man/man1/git.1.gz
                /usr/share/man/man3/Git.3pm.gz
                /usr/share/man/man1/diff.1.gz
```

Comment: That's funny -- they choosed the same example. Thanks!

Comment: The [man-db](http://man-db.nongnu.org/) implementation of `man` added this in 2009 apparently: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/man-db.git/commit/?id=7de45db026166ea55f9b7c240928ef0de0245a3f

Answer (score 1):

Git may have a reference for `diff` in `git` that points to `git-diff`.